# yii validation only if another field is present

Tags: yii

I have two fields in my form named `start date` and `end date`. I want to validate `end date` only if `start date` is present.

In rails, we have `:if`. Do we have anything similar in `yii`?

Comment: I just completed this kinda of validation with Yii. you can refer it from here. http://chevronscode.com/index.php/yii-model-rules-dynamic-required-if-extension.html

Comment: In **Yii2** you can use the [`when`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation) property.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define your custom function for validation .

define rule :

```
array('end_date','checkEndDate');
```

define custom function:

```
public function checkEndDate($attributes,$params)
{
  if($this->start_date){
     if(!$this->validate_end_date($this->end_date))
         $this->addError('end_date','Error Message');
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

validation of one field based on other can be done in model rules method .
Here is the rules method.

```
        ['start_date','required','when'=>function($model) {
            return $model->end_date != '';
        }]
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Note: the above solution is for Yii 2

Comment: You should take care of [client validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation) too, or inhibit it adding the element `'enableClientValidation'=>false` to the above array

Answer (score 2):

For the lazy, add the conditional validation to the model's `beforeValidate` method:

```
if($this->start_date){
  if(!$this->validate_end_date($this->end_date))
    $this->addError('end_date','Error Message');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validate()` [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#validate-detail) to validate attributes **individually**, so you can first validate `start_date` and skip validation if there are errors with it, something like:

```
<?php
// ... code ...
// in your controller's actionCreate for the particular model

// ... other code ...

if(isset($_POST['SomeModel'])){
    $model->attributes=$_POST['SomeModel'];
    if ($model->validate(array('start_date'))){
    // alright no errors with start_date, so continue validating others, and saving record

         if ($model->validate(array('end_date'))){
         // assuming you have only two fields in the form, 
         // if not obviously you need to validate all the other fields,
         // so just pass rest of the attribute list to validate() instead of only end_date

              if($model->save(false)) // as validation is already done, no need to validate again while saving
                  $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
         }
    }
}
// ... rest of code ...
// incase you didn't know error information is stored in the model instance when we call validate, so when you render, the error info will be passed to the view
```

Alternatively you could also use the `skipOnError` attribute of [CValidator class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#skipOnError-detail):

```
// in your model's rules, mark every validator rule that includes end_date as skipOnError,
// so that if there is any error with start_date, validation for end_date will be skipped
public function rules(){
     return array(
         array('start_date, end_date', 'required', 'skipOnError'=>true),
         array('start_date, end_date', 'date', 'skipOnError'=>true),
         // The following rule is used by search().
         // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
         array('id, start_date, end_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
     );
}
```

Hope this helps.
Disclaimer: I'm not sure about the skipOnError solution, it might be affected by the order of validators, you can test it (I have not tested yet), and find out if it works. The individual validation solution will of course work any day.

Comment: let me know if you require any clarifications.