# How to add dependency between attribute validation in Yii CActiveRecord?

Tags: validation, activerecord, yii, attributes

I have a model that represents key-value settings by using CActiveRecord.

The database table has the following structure:

```
| Field       | Type         |
| key         | varchar(255) |
| category    | varchar(255) |
| default     | varchar(255) |
| is_editable | tinyint(1)   |
| is_required | tinyint(1)   |
| name        | varchar(255) |
| description | text         |
| value       | varchar(255) |
| create_at   | datetime     |
| update_at   | datetime     |
```

What needs to be done is to have the `value` parameter required only when the `is_required` attribute is `true`.

The `is_required` attribute is added the first time, when the scenario is `create`.

The process should proceed with custom validation method I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to the problem:

The `rules()` method should look something like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('key', 'required'),
        array('name, is_required, default', 'required', 'on'=>'create'),
        array('key, category, default, type, name, value', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('category, value, name, is_required', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

We can override the `isAttributeRequired` function so it has in mind the additional check.

```
public function isAttributeRequired($attribute)
{
    if($attribute == 'value' && $this->is_required)
        return true;

    return parent::isAttributeRequired($attribute);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. But it does not work for me. It is not called =(. I can't find the place in any class where it is called.

Comment: Check the first version of the answer, before it got corrected: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18400541/revisions

Comment: Yeah. I did something like that. I found it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543451/yii-validation-only-if-another-field-is-present